# Best way to fix a malfunctioning Pixel

Tags: display

I've looked up several times about how to fix a stuck pixel; but all their classifications of stuck do not really apply to this.

I have a single pixel that's blue, however if I mouse over it; it turns white. So that means the other micro pixels are working fine to produce white, but the blue one obviously won't deactivate.

Comment: Your pixel is evidently only stuck and not dead. Have you tried the methods in [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-software-solutions-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-your-lcd-monitor/)?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix hardware problem is via hardware fix. Replace the martix.

All software solutions will hide the problem, not correct it.